# the code quality report is generated and stored as an artifact, but it's not appearing in the GitLab Merge Request (MR) widget

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

The code quality report is generated and stored as an artifact, but it's not appearing in the GitLab Merge Request (MR) widget, I have verified that the path of the location are correct, the "Code quality" checkbox is also enabled under "Merge request widgets.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1OwL.png)

Can someone assist me in identifying the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are there any reports available for comparison on the target branch ?

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/testing/code_quality.html
[image]

Comment: No , no reports are available for comparison on the target branch